# Event occuring for each row separatly

Tags: mysql

I want to create an Event for Table :-

```
ACCOUNTS(id char(5),balance decimal(10,2), date_created date)
```

Value for the `DATE_CREATED` column will always be = `NOW()`, i.e. the date when the row was inserted in the table

I want that the balance for each row gets increased by 2% after **every 31 Days**, according to its  `DATE_CREATED` column, i.e. after (`DATE_CREATED+31 Days`) for each row.

I wanted to know whether it is possible or not and if it is possible then what would be the code for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to write an `UPDATE` statement that uses `DATEDIFF` and `MOD`

Try something like:

```
UPDATE Accounts 
SET Balance = Balance * 1.02 
WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),date_created) MOD 31 = 0;
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25182/1).

You can schedule this to run daily.  That's probably your best approach.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.Can you tell what if, I want to UPDATE the BALANCE after 1 hr if I had given TIME instead of DATE ?

Comment: You could use TIMESTAMPDIFF -- something like: TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date_created, now())

Comment: Just a note -- you're currently storing your data as a DATE -- to get hour differentials, change that to a DATETIME and store the time as well.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes,I wrote this code: CREATE EVENT `temp_event`
ON SCHEDULE every 1 second
DO 
begin
-- update balance by 2%
UPDATE Account 
SET Balance = Balance * 1.02 
WHERE timestampdiff(second,date_created,current_timestamp) MOD 300 = 0;
 end $$........but the problem is that after I enter the balance,suppose 3000,so it updates the balance before 300 seconds and then the balance= 3060, is updated according to the event,i.e.,after every 300 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

This will run every day but based on the `where clause` it will update the table.

```
CREATE EVENT `myEvent`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO BEGIN
    -- update balance by 2%
    UPDATE yourtable
    SET balance = balance * 1.02
    WHERE DateDiff(CurDate(), created_date) MOD 31 = 0
END;
```

By any chance if you are looking for updataing a `Created_Date` that has a 31 days interval from today, then the `Where clause`:

```
WHERE Date_Format(Date_Add(CurDate(), interval 31 day),'%Y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(CurDate(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

or

`WHERE DateDiff(CurDate(), created_date) = 31`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html to get to know the syntax better.

Comment: perhaps I was mistaken from OPs requirement, but I thought the result was to update the balance every 31 days.  31, 62, etc, like an ongoing increase as time passes.  That's why I used MOD. Nice answer showing the event code! - +1 for that!

Comment: @sgeddes, thanks! You are absolutely right, OP had bold font **every 31 days**, so it makes sense to have `MOD` ofcourse :).

Comment: @bonCodigo, thanks! for helping me.Can you tell what if, I want to UPDATE the BALANCE after 1 hr if I had given TIME instead of DATE ?

Comment: Glad :) you can use `ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR` or `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR`

Comment: @bonCodigo ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR....the BALANCE gets updated once ,before the specified time....suppose balance=3000 then it gets updated to 3060 and then it updates according to the time specified in the EVENT.

Comment: Because once the date difference is `31`, within that day that condition is true. Hence for every hour it will keep on updating.. `:)` You may want to have another column to check if the balance is already updated if you are going to stick with this `hourly event`...

Comment: @bonCodigo My problem got solved using this:                  UPDATE temp                                                         
SET Balance = Balance * 1.02                                        
WHERE timestampdiff(hour,date_created,current_timestamp) >0 and   timestampdiff(hour,date_created,current_timestamp) MOD 5 = 0 ;

Comment: @bonCodigo I can choose only one answer and the statement "DateDiff(CurDate(), created_date) MOD 31 = 0" solved my problem which was first given by **Sgeddes** but I thank you for your help on 'CREATE EVENT' syntax.

Comment: Well regardless I wonder all the comments/questions you made here on `SCHEDULING` though.. well NVM :) for `mod` he deserves it :)